Confusion on finding the algebra generated by the family $\{ \{r\}|r\in\mathbb{R}\}$
We need to find the algebra generated by this family, which means we need to find the smallest algebra containing the family. My approach is as follows. For any algebra $\mathscr{A}$ containing $\{ \{r\}|r\in\mathbb{R} \}$, by definition, it must meet the criteria

$\{r\}\in\mathscr{A}$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$

$\{r\}^c = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{r \}\in\mathscr{A}$

For any $r,r'\in\mathbb{R}$, $\{r\}\cup\{r'\}\in\mathscr{A}$, for $r\neq r'$

$\mathscr{A}\neq\emptyset$


Then we should expect $\mathscr{A}=\{ \{r\},\mathbb{R}\setminus\{r\}, \{r,r'\} \}=\{A_i \}_{i=1}^3$. To find the smallest such algebra, we take the intersection
$$\bigcap\mathscr{A} = \{s\in\mathbb{R}|\forall_{A_i\in\mathscr{A}}s\in A_i \}=\{s\in\mathbb{R}|s\in\{r\},s\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{r\}, s\in\{r,r' \} \} $$
This is where I get confused and think I'm misunderstanding something, because there is no such $s$ that meets all of these requirements; condition 1 and condition 2 in the way I've constructed the algebra contradict one another. Can someone give me some tips? Thanks.

It is the class of all finite sets and complements of finite sets.

@geetha290krm thanks, but I just don't see this from the definition. ${r}$ and ${r}$ may both consist of unions of other reals, so I see the finite sets thing, but still from the definition, I don't see how there could be an $s\in\mathbb{R}$ as well as in $\mathbb{R}\setminus{r}$.

Although your 2. and 3. follow from the definition of algebra, they are not the definition. By definition, $A$ has to satisfy

for all $X \in A$, $X^c \in A$;
for all $X,Y \in A$, $X \cup Y \in A$.

Then you'll see that the algebra generated by $\{r\}$, $r \in {\mathbb R}$ consists of all subsets of $\mathbb R$ that are finite or whose complemement is finite.

I see this from these criteria as well as intuition, but I still don't see it from trying to take the intersection of $A$. I may be constructing it wrong, but is this (intersection of $A$) not generally the approach for solving these kinds of problems?

Taking the intersection over all algebras containing ${r}$, $r \in {\mathbb R}$ does give the smallest algebra, but doesn't really tell you what it is. For that, you need some intuition, and then a proof that your intuition works. In this case, it is easy to prove that the set of all finite and cofinite subsets of ${\mathbb R}$ is an algebra and then you use an induction argument to show that it is the smallest (i.e., contained in all applicable algebras).
